# Google Street View add-in problem

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, google-maps, google-earth

I recently started having a problem with the google street view addin in ArcMap. When I press on the "Street view" icon this shuts ArcMap down entirely! it used to work fine and I have no idea what is causing this problem.

Anyone face this issue before?

I also get the following error :

> no gui components found in this add-in. add-in version does not match

when attempting to install the add-in from the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a very simple version I've made:

[Google Street View Python Add-in](http://ianbroad.com/google-street-view-python-addin-for-arcmap/)

Unlike the SIGGIS version, it doesn't show the Street View in a window in ArcMap. It just opens the location in your internet browser.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I fixed it by downloading the latest version of this tool right here:

http://www.siggis.be/en/products/siggis-street-amp-bird-view